# Is the integral test not valid for negative, upwards-trending functions?

Tags: summation, indefinite-integrals

The integral test states that given a function $f(n)$ that is positive, continuous, and decreasing on the interval $x \geq 1$, and a series $a_n = f(n)$, $\int_1^\infty f(n)dn$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ either both converge or diverge.

Is this not necessarily true for negative, continuous, increasing functions? Why so?

Comment: Yes, it is true for such functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is negative, increasing and continuous, you can apply the integral test to $b_n=-a_n=-f(n)$...

Comment: The answer is so obvious that, forgetting that I can just take the negative, it went right over my head. Thanks!